# Why does this Relay not oscillate

Tags: relay, oscillator

[image]

I have built the above circuit. The relay switches once, but then stops. Why does this not oscillate, as the current is broken every time it connects?

Comment: It should - assuming reasonable actual values. The LED will never light. How about some more information?

Comment: Probably oscillating so fast that you can't hear/see it. The contacts will barely open. It might whistle is you listen closely. By the time the contact start to open ever so slightly, the relay immediately de-energizes.

Comment: In which position does it stop?

Comment: Insert a capacitor across the points to the coil. That will allow current to flow long enough for the diode to energize.

Comment: 1V won't drive a relay or a LED. Given this part of the circuit is wrong how can anyone have confidence that you have wired it up correctly? Detail is darn important!!

Comment: Note that you need at least 2.5V to light the LED and you **must** add a series resistor between the LED and the relay contact to avoid damaging it.

Comment: Also you will want a flyback diode across the coil to prevent arcing across the contacts.

Comment: @JohnD is arcing an issue because of this particular configuration ?

Comment: @efox29 Any time you have an inductor (relay coil) carrying current, if you interrupt the current the voltage will rise to whatever value it needs to to keep the current continuous in that instant. V=L*di/dt So it will arc across the contacts unless a flyback diode is across the coil to provide a path for the current.

Comment: @JohnD  I agree if it is with this particular config, but with a typical relay config where the contacts are not in contact with the relay coil, I don't necessary see how a flyback would  prevent arcing on the contacts. The diode would protect the surrounding circuitry like a mosfet, but not sure I follow with the arcing part.

Comment: @efox29 Sure, if the contacts are not in series with an inductor, there's no need for a flyback diode to protect them.  There may still be a need for a flyback diode across the coil if there's something switching the coil current on and off that can be damaged by a large voltage spike, and there may be a need for a flyback diode across an inductive load to protect the contacts, but otherwise the contacts are safe from arcing.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities as to why the relay does not oscillate:
  1) If the LED lit once, then the battery gets discharged after the first actuation and therefore can't repeat the activation.
  2) The relay contact IS oscillating, but you can't detect it (too high).
  3) The battery does not have sufficient voltage to "completely" break the circuit, but you "hear"the relay click once.

To give you a more precise answer, I need to know the relay specs, the battery's power capability, and what is the LED doing (full brightness, dull, off)?